# is it possible to upload android app that use dagger hilt to playstore?

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have an app using dagger hilt. Is it possible to upload the app the to play store? or should I convert it to dagger 2? I starting to use Hilt and it makes me hate dagger 2 so much

Comment: Why would one want to upload the test-application to the Play Store? This makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dagger and Dagger Hilt are generating code. This is transparent from the Play Store perspective.